# How to read PCM audio data from Swift Data variable type into AVAudioPCMBuffer?

Tags: swift, audio, avaudioplayer, pcm, avaudioengine

I'm working on a project where I'd like to play raw PCM data for IOS using swift. So far I've been able to load the PCM data from a local file into a swift Data variable like so

```
    let audioData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL) //Read data into data var
```

where fileURL contains the path to a PCM file.

Next, I'd like to play the audioData somehow; currently my ideas are to either

1. add a WAV header onto the audioData, write the data to file, then play it using AVAudioPlayer
2. somehow copy the data over to a AVAudioPCMBuffer and play it from the buffer using AVAudioEngine

Unfortunately, since I'm very new to swift and audio in general I'm pretty lost on how to actually program either of these routes